# How to access andriod to my pcs hardrive using wifi

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-4, data-connection

I would like to connect my samsung galaxy s4 over wifi with my pcs harddrive. It should be the same way as by the remote desktop apps but indstead of them only to use the pc hardrive. I want to get and send files between my whole 1 TB hardrive therefore I don't want to use cloud services like dropbox. Also I don't need to sync.

Answer (score 0):

[AirStream: Stream PC on mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nityaalabs.airstream) could help you. There is no root or registration required.

Answer (score 0):

I do all manner of communication between android and Windows. I have several android TV PCs with monitors used as thin clients, and I use TV PCs for streaming on big TVs. For remoting into Windows use Microsoft Remote Desktop Beta from the play store. Many android file browsers connect to Windows file sharing. I use ES File Explorer Pro to copy files and update the TV PCs. I use FolderSync Pro to backup my cell phone to Windows. This all works flawlessly and is easy to set up if you have Windows security knowledge. Also use a fixed IP address for the Windows machine, using that as the server name. The Windows machine name often is not found via DNS, but the IP address always works. Do not include a domain name in server set up for android apps.

Windows security is a pain. Do not take a shortcut and give too much access to your android devices. Create a user on the Windows machine for the intended purpose, and give that user access to one or more folders required. It's fine to give full access to that user for just those folders. Permission must be given at the Windows share name and the Windows folder. These are two different sets of permissions.